# Android: ImageView через путь к файлу

Tags: android, java

Мне нужно картинку по адресу, вроде: **/mnt/sdcard/img.jpg** вставить в  ImageView. Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
File image = new File(path);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());
webView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Я получаю путь к файлу из Галереи, но приложение не видит путь к файлу,пишит, что файл отсутствует . Но в файловом менеджере файл есть и в галереи тоже.

```
if (arg0 == button4){
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}
```

Как я получаю путь:

```
private String UriToBit(Uri uri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(index);
}
```

Я пробовал функцию UriToBit() проверить на try - catch, но всё прошло успешно.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413401/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-uri?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

А может прав не хватает: [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)?