# Как получить путь к файлу из URI?

Tags: java, android

Получаю фото из галлереи.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
```

в таком виде

```
content://media/external/images/media/18
```

а как получить реальный путь с названием файла?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае если нужно просто обрезать протокол (media/external/images/media/18):

```
String path = selectedImage.uri.toString();
```

Реальный путь:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Сама картинка по URI:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
```

Comment: Все заработало! Огромная благодарность за оперативность и четкость!